# Understanding proof of theorem 1, appendix to chapter 8 in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am trying to understand Spivak's proof of theorem 1 in the appendix to chapter 8. He uses a lemma in the proof, which in turn uses two statements (i) and (ii).

## Prerequisites

> Suppose that we have two intervals $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$ with the common end-point $b$, and a function $f$ that is continuous on $[a,c]$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and suppose that the following two statements hold
>
> (i) if $x$ and $y$ are in $[a,b]$ and $|x-y|<\delta_1$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$,
>
> (ii) if $x$ and $y$ are in $[b,c]$ and $|x-y|<\delta_2$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.
>
> We'd like to know if there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are points in $[a,c]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$.

### Lemma

> Let $a<b<c$ and let $f$ be continuous on the interval $[a,c]$. Let $\epsilon>0$, and suppose that (i) and (ii) hold. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that,
>
> if $x$ and $y$ are in $[a,c]$ and $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

## Questions

### Theorem 1

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

### Proof

> For $\epsilon>0$ let's say that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,b]$ if there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $y$ and $z$ in $[a,b]$,
>
> if $|y-z|<\delta$, then $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$.
>
> Then we're trying to prove that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,b]$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Consider any particular $\epsilon>0$. Let
>
> $A=\{x: a\leq x\leq b \ \text{and} \ f \ \text{is} \ \epsilon\text{-good on} \ [a,x]\}$.
>
> Then $A\neq \emptyset$ (since $a$ is in $A$), and $A$ is bounded above (by $b$), so $A$ has a least upper bound $\alpha$.... Suppose that we had $\alpha< b$. Since $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$, there is $\delta_0>0$ such that, if $|y-\alpha|<\delta_0$, then $|f(y)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon/2$. Consequently, if $|y-\alpha|<\delta_0$ and $|z-\alpha|<\delta_0$, then $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$. So $f$ is surely $\epsilon$-good on the interval $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$.

Why is $f$ surely $\epsilon$-good on the interval $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$?

> On the other hand, since $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $A$, it is also clear that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,\alpha-\delta_0]$.

How can we know that $a< \alpha-\delta_0$?

> Then the Lemma implies that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,a+\delta_0]$, so $a+\delta_0$ is in $A$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is an upper bound.

I am quoting from the third edition (Cambridge University Press) and I believe $a+\delta_0$ must be a typo. It should be $\alpha+\delta_0$, shouldn't it?

> To complete the proof we just have to show that $\alpha=b$ is actually in $A$.... Since $f$ is continuous at $b$, there is some $\delta_0>0$ such that, if $|b-y|<\delta_0$, then $|f(y)-f(b)|<\epsilon/2$. So $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[b-\delta_0,b]$.

Why is $f$ $\epsilon$-good on $[b-\delta_0,b]$?

Comment: "How can we know that $a<α−δ_0$?" you probably mean $\le$

Answer (score 2):

> Why is $f$ surely $\epsilon$-good on the interval $[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$?

Because if $x,y\in[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ then $|x-\alpha|\le\delta_0,|y-\alpha|\le\delta_0$ therefore: $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(\alpha)+f(\alpha)-f(y)|\le|f(x)-f(\alpha)|+|f(y)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon$$

> How can we know that $a<\alpha−\delta_0$?

Strictly speaking, one should specify $\delta_0$ with the criterion that $a\le\alpha-\delta_0$. It is quite easy to see $\alpha>a$, so this is possible. Since such $\delta_0$ exist at any sufficiently small size, there is no loss of generality in asserting this, and many authors will do this without comment. In fact, we need $a\le\alpha-\delta_0$ (and $\alpha+\delta_0\le b$) for $f$ to even make sense on $[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$. To reiterate, you can enforce these condition anyway, don't worry about it!

> It should be $\alpha+\delta_0$, shouldn't it?

Yes, it should be.

> Why is $f$ $\epsilon$-good on $[b−\delta_0,b]$?

For the same reasons that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$. It follows by the continuity-at-a-point ($b$) inequality and the triangle inequality.

---

This proof is essentially a proof by real induction. A more general proof might be to observe that $[a,b]$ is compact, thus any continuous function thereon is uniformly continuous. I won't prove this in full generality (metric spaces) but you can apply these ideas elsewhere.

Fix an $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at every point, for all $x\in[a,b]$ there exist (given) $\delta_x>0$ and $|x-y|<\delta_x\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$. Then, for reasons described above, $|f(u)-f(v)|<\epsilon$ whenever $u,v\in(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\cap[a,b]$. We have an open cover: $$[a,b]=\bigcup_{x\in[a,b]}(x-\delta_x/3,x+\delta_x/3)\cap[a,b]$$(Yes, divided by $3$) which admits a finite subcover - by compactness - indexed by some $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$: $$[a,b]=\bigcup_{i=1}^n(x_i-\delta_{x_i}/3,x_i+\delta_{x_i}/3)\cap[a,b]$$

Define: $$\delta:=\min_{1\le i\le n}\delta_{x_i}/3>0$$

Suppose $x,y\in[a,b]$ and $|x-y|<\delta$. There is some $x_i$ such that $|x-x_i|<\delta_{x_i}/3$, so: $$|y-x_i|=|y-x+x-x_i|\le|y-x|+|x-x_i|<\delta+\delta_{x_i}/3\le\frac{2}{3}\delta_{x_i}<\delta_{x_i}$$

Therefore $x$ and $y$ are both in $(x_i-\delta_{x_i},x_i+\delta_{x_i})\cap[a,b]$. By definition of the $\delta_{x_i}$, we have that: $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$As $x,y$ were arbitrary, we conclude that this $\delta$ makes $f$ $\epsilon$-good on all $[a,b]$. As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we get that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: In your first answer you write "Because if $x,y\in[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ then $|x-\alpha|<\delta_0,|y-\alpha|<\delta_0$...". I would claim that if $x,y\in[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ then $|x-\alpha|\leq\delta_0,|y-\alpha|\leq\delta_0$, i.e. changing $<$ to $\leq$. This is because $x,y$ are in the closed interval $[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$.

Comment: Why is it easy to see that $a<\alpha$? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @schn Just because $f$ is continuous at $a$, it is good on some $[a,a+\delta’]$ if $\delta’$ satisfies the continuity-at-$a$ challenge for $\epsilon/2$ (See more detailed arguments of the same in my post)

Comment: I do not understand how you conclude that $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[\alpha−\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$. We require that $|x-y|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$, whereas you have two inequalities: $|x-\alpha|\le\delta_0$ and $|y-\alpha|\le\delta_0$.

Comment: @schn I proved that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$. That means it really doesn’t matter what I take $\delta$ to be! $\delta$ may be one googolplex or it may be the Planck length. Either way, the desired inequality holds on that interval regardless of how close $x$ is to $y$. So, $f$ is epsilon-good on that interval

Comment: We have $|x-\alpha|<\delta_0\implies |f(x)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon/2$ by continuity at $\alpha$. Does that implication also hold if $|x-\alpha|\le\delta_0$?

Comment: @schn No. That is a small mistake in the original proof. However, I and the author both failed to spot that for two (essentially the same) reasons. A) we can just as well work with open intervals, and B) the author could have specified $\delta_0$ to satisfy the continuity inequality with an $\le$ sign. There is no loss in generality and it really does not matter!

Comment: Maybe a small detail, but don't you think it is confusing when Spivak writes at the end of the proof "Since $f$ is continuous at $b$, there is some $\delta_0>0$ such that, if $|b-y|<\delta_0$, then..." Since $b$ seems to be a boundary point, we should have $b-\delta_0<y\le b$ instead of $|b-y|<\delta_0$, i.e. $f$ is only right-continuous at $b$.

Comment: @schn You’re right. Strictly speaking, as $f$ is not formally defined outside of $[a,b]$, we should write: “for $b-\delta_0\le y\le b$” but it does not affect the proof.

Answer (score 2):

1. > Why is $f$ surely $\epsilon$-good on the interval $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$?

Because $\forall y,z\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0],$ if $|y-z|<2\delta_0$ then $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ (even if one of the two numbers $y$ or $z$ is equal to $\alpha\pm\delta_0,$ e.g. $y=\alpha-\delta_0,$ because then, $z\ne\alpha+\delta_0,$ so that $|f(y)-f(\alpha)|\le\epsilon/2$ and $|f(\alpha)-f(z)|<\epsilon/2$).

More precisely, everything we said was not on $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ but on $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]\cap[a,b].$

2. > How can we know that $a\le\alpha-\delta_0$?

We can't. At this stage of the proof, $\alpha$ might as well be equal to $a.$ But we don't bother. If $a>\alpha-\delta_0$ then $[a,\alpha-\delta_0]$ is empty and $f$'s goodness on the emptyset is vacuously true.

3. > It should be $α+δ_0,$ shouldn't it?

Yes indeed.

4. > Why is $f$ $\epsilon$-good on $[b-\delta_0,b]$?

Same argument as for question 1:  $\forall y,z\in[b-\delta_0,b],$ if $|y-z|<\delta_0$ then $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ (again, even if $y$ or $z$ equals $b-\delta_0$ or $b$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the difference between $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]\cap[a,b].$ and $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$?

Comment: ?? $A\cap B=A\iff A\subset B,$ which may not be the case for your two intervals (a posteriori, we are even sure it is not the case, since $\alpha+\delta_0=b+\delta_0>b$). And we have to restrict to $[a,b]$ because $f$ is not defined outside.

Comment: Why did you choose $2\delta_0$ in your first answer? Why not just $\delta_0$?

Comment: Because it is the largest number which does the job. If $y,z\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ then $y,z$ are always $\le\delta_0$-close to $\alpha.$ The additional condition $|y-z|<2\delta_0$ is just to prevent them to be both bounds of this closed interval, otherwise we would just have $\dots\le\epsilon$ instead of $\dots<\epsilon.$

Comment: You claim that if even $y=\alpha+\delta_0$, then $|f(y)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon/2$ holds. However, if $y=\alpha+\delta_0$, then the implication $|y-\alpha|<\delta_0\implies |f(y)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon/2$ does not hold, contradicting continuity at $\alpha$.

Comment: This *[implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table)* does hold for *all* $y\in[a,b]$, by definition of $\delta_0.$ It implies that (if $\alpha+\delta_0\le b$) $|f(\alpha+\delta_0)-f(\alpha)|\le\epsilon/2$ (by continuity). Similarly (if $\alpha-\delta_0\ge a$) $|f(\alpha-\delta_0)-f(\alpha)|\le\epsilon/2.$ And if $y,z\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ and $|y-z|<2\delta_0,$ one of them will have its image *strictly* $\epsilon/2$-close to $f(\alpha).$